# Package Permission Set (Custom field permission on standard object)

Tags: managed-package, permission-sets

We want to add a Permission Set to our managed package. 
Is it possible to add permissions for custom fields on a standard object?
(Will the Permission Set remain in the package, after installing it?)

The Salesforce doc states that it is possible to add custom field permissions, but it also states that it is not possible to add standard object permissions.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=distribution_perm_sets_profile_settings.htm&language=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried it myself.
A packaged Permission Set with permissions for custom fields on a standard object, will remain in the package after installing it.

(Tried with an unmanaged package, though)